# Janrain Social Login

Tags: javascript, janrain

I am using [Janrain](http://janrain.com/) to implement social login of my site and everything is working pretty fine. But when running in mobile, the page that pops up is not closing and the process can't continue. I have to close the page, come back to original one and, then, the login completes.

Any idea how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

When using the Janrain Social Login(Engage) only widget inside of a UIWebView you need to disable the use of the default pop-up window workflow and use redirects:

```
// --- Mobile WebView ------------------------------------------------------
//janrain.settings.popup = false;
//janrain.settings.tokenAction = 'url';
```

The primary reason is that the UIWebView component in iOS prevents pop-up windows.

The above settings should help you achieve the functionality you are looking for.

These settings also apply to the Janrain Registration (Capture) Widget but you typically also need these additional settings:

```
// --- Mobile WebView ------------------------------------------------------
//janrain.settings.capture.redirectFlow = true;
//janrain.settings.capture.redirectUri = location.href;
```

Of course these settings may not apply in all situations.

http://developers.janrain.com/reference/javascript-api/social-login-js-api/settings/